# APN | Push notification giving OpenSSL error randomly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, apple-push-notifications

I'm using `gem Houston` for sending push notifications to Apple Devices from my Rails application.

But since 8th of April, it started crashing a lot. At sometime of day it crashes for about 70-90% of push requests.

Found **[this issue](https://github.com/nomad/houston/issues/114)** on Houston issues.

And **[this discussion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/44677)** on Apple Forums.

But in vain till now.

Error Trace:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A):
  app/services/push_notification_service.rb:32:in `send_ios_notification'
  app/services/push_notification_service.rb:18:in `send_notification_to'
  app/services/push_notification_service.rb:6:in `send_notification_to_driver'
  app/models/concerns/request_ticket_node_requests.rb:56:in `block in send_notifications'
  app/models/concerns/request_ticket_node_requests.rb:52:in `send_notifications'
  app/models/concerns/request_ticket_node_requests.rb:22:in `broadcast_notifications_to_drivers'
  app/controllers/api/user_app/request_tickets_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

Comment: Joining in. Got the exact same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concluded same as the problem at Apple's server end as it vanished by default after few days.